# How do I count the number duplicate fields in a non duplicate array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, foreach

I have a (Messages) collection full of users with read and unread messages, similar to the one illustrated below:

```
userName               READ MESSAGES     unreadMessages
Paul Otterson             1                0
Vincent Guily             0                1   
Paul Otterson             0                1
Vincent Guily             0                1 
Paul Otterson             1                0
```

I am able to eliminate "userName" duplicates, which I accomplish by this helper code:

```
Template.messages.helpers({

'Names': function () {

var loggedUserName = Meteor.user().services.facebook.name;
var lastId;
var counter = 0;

var transactions =  Messages.find({userName: loggedUserName}, {sort: {time: -1}}).fetch();
var users = _.uniq(transactions,true, function(messages) {return messages.userName}); 

    users.forEach (function (row) {
         counter +=1;
                     });                     
    console.log(counter+ " number of users in Messages collection");

return users;}

});
```

Helper:

```
<template name="messages">
{{#each Names}}
    {{userName}} has {{unreadMessages}} Unread messages </br>
{{/ each}}
</template>
```

Yielding this

```
Paul Otterson has 0 Unread messages
Vincent Guily has 1 Unread messages
```

Since some of the users have a specific number of unread messages, How do I write a helper code to display the number of unread messages per user?

To clarify I would like to achieve the below:

```
Paul Otterson has 1 Unread messages
Vincent Guily has 2 Unread messages
```

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: _count the amount of_ what? Please use the informative titles.

Comment: Maybe you could do with a [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Comment: use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/): [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by userName and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) unreadMessages

Comment: @Joao thanks for pointing me in that direction. Would you kindly mind demonstrating in code how to achieve this?

Comment: this has a pretty simple solution and no aggregation needed, I think. please paste your "messages" schema and how you save who read the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you can use the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to groups all the input documents by the `userName` field and applies the accumulator expression **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** to the group to get the total unread and read messages count.

Your pipeline would look like this:

```
var pipeline = [        
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userName",
            "readMessages": { "$sum": "$read" },
            "unreadMessages": { "$sum": "$unread" }        
        }
    },
    {
         "$project": {
             "userName": "$_id", "_id": 0,
             "unreadMessages": 1, "readMessages": 1
         }
    }
];
var users = Messages.aggregate(pipeline);
```

You can add the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation in Meteor:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Since this package exposes **`.aggregate`** method on Mongo.Collection instances, you can then call the method to get the result array with the document that has the count field.